# 1px gap at the bottom of absolute positioned div in IE when using border radius and transform scale

Tags: css, internet-explorer, transform, scale

**Summary**

- I have a container
- Inside that container I have an image without a set height
- Inside the image div i have an img tag and another absolute positioned div
- The absolute positioned div sits at the bottom of the image
- When the image container / div doesn't have a set defined height, a 1px gap appears at the bottom
- When hovering over the item, the image scales

**Question**

How can I get rid of this gap? It's apparent by default but is worse on hover when the image scales

```css
body {
  background: #ebebeb;
}
.item {
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
}
.item:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #999;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image .border {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 5% 5% 0 0;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">

  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg"/>
    <div class="border"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Link to codepen example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKddOB

Comment: I don't have IE running on the machine I'm using right now, so I can't replicate your problem. But if I had to take a guess, I'd suggest adding `display: block;` to the image. I get a lot of weird gaps and stuff on `img` elements if I don't use `display: block;` because `img` defaults to `display: inline;`, so there's usually some weird whitespace stuff going on.

Comment: Hi Jesse - Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, that's not it.